# Sum of comma separated string

Tags: javascript, string, sum

I have a string like:
string = "Green 3, Red 5, Blue 6, ";

I would like to add the numeric values together, ie the answer to this string should be: 3 + 5 + 6 = 14

I have removed the none numeric values from the string but can't find the way to add the digit!

var string = string.replace(/\D/g,"");
so far I get 356 and not 14!

Comment: `string.match(/\d+/g)` then sum the array elems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Please Rate Me If this helps you...</title>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var string = "Green 3, Red 5, Blue 6";
        var separeted = string.split(",");
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < separeted.length; i++) {
            sum += parseInt(separeted[i].toString().match(/(\d+)/));
        }
        alert(sum);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update sum += separeted[i].toString().match(/(\d+)/) != null ? parseInt(separeted[i].toString().match(/(\d+)/)) : 0;

Comment: reduce is a good option which is given by the ECMAScript 2015

Answer (score 3):

use [string.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var string = "Green 3, Red 5, Blue 6, "
var result = string.match(/\d+/g).reduce(function(a,b) {return +a + +b;});
```

which is equal to

```
var string = "Green 3, Red 5, Blue 6, "
var array = string.match(/\d+/g);
var result = array.reduce(function(a,b) {
    return +a + +b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing that:

```
string.split(',').reduce(function(sum, cur) {
  var n = cur.match(/(\d+)/);
  return sum + (n && parseInt(n[1],10) || 0);
}, 0);
//=> 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...hope this will help u

```
<span id="foo">280ms</span>
<span>sum:</span><span id="spid"></span>

var text = $('#foo').text();
output = text.split(","),
var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(output[i].toString().match(/(\d+)/));
    }
$("#spid").text(sum)
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krishnadevacc/3n5nonu4/)

Comment: This won't work with the required input `"Green 3, Red 5, Blue 6, "`